# Can we use same jquery functionality twice once on hover and another on click?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have main menu which contain 6 element or main categories - when we hover over these main menus then we can see their sub menus or categories.

http://newiagadvisors.advisorproducts.com/home

**My Requirement is like this way:**

it’s possible to have the **sub-menus or categories** appear as choices when someone **clicks** on the pictures as well - in the same way while **hovering** over main menu we see their sub categories or menus?

I want same menu hover functionality on **click event** when someone click on picture

Below is the jquery code for main menu dropdown on hover event:

```
$(function()
{
    $("ul.dropdown li").hover(function()
    {
        $(this).addClass("hover");
        $('ul:first',this).css('visibility', 'visible');
    }, function()
    {
        $(this).removeClass("hover");
        $('ul:first',this).css('visibility', 'hidden');
    });
    $("ul.dropdown li ul li:has(ul)").find("a:first").append(" &raquo; ");
});
```

Comment: Yes you can, why not give it a go! `$('img').click(function(){ do stuff });` - [http://api.jquery.com/click/](http://api.jquery.com/click/)

Comment: But how do you envision it to work? On click you show the sub menus but then when do they disappear? On the second click?

Comment: If we give this same functionality on click event for image then how can we link or show the same submenu appears on click?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
var images = $('#banner img'),
    menuItems = $('.dropdown.sub-menu > li');

images.click(function(){
    var index = images.index(this);

    var li = menuItems.eq(index),
        sublist = li.find('ul:first');

    if(sublist.length)
    {
        li.addClass("hover");
        sublist.css('visibility', 'visible').show();
    }
});
```

Comment: I tried your code and it works but the only thing is left - when we move our mouse out of that box then it hides the subnav - can it be possible to show sub nav until user can click outside ?

Comment: @SushilRaghav `$("ul.dropdown li").hover` hide it, you can add variable to detect how submenu was opened and do not allow to hide it.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the same function for different Even listeners there will not be any problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use `bind()`, however bind isn't compatible with [hover](http://api.jquery.com/hover/), so you can use `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` instead. Note that hover is a shortcut for those two handlers.

```
  $("ul.dropdown li").bind( {
        'mouseenter' : function(){
          $(this).addClass("hover");
          $('ul:first',this).css('visibility', 'visible');
        }, 
        'mouseleave': function()
        {
          $(this).removeClass("hover");
          $('ul:first',this).css('visibility', 'hidden');
        },
        'click': function()
        {
          if( $(this).hasClass("hover") ){
            $(this).removeClass("hover");
            $('ul:first',this).css('visibility', 'hidden');
          } else {
            $(this).addClass("hover");
            $('ul:first',this).css('visibility', 'visible');
          }
        }
      });
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply dude - it make so many thing clear to me in jquery :)

Answer (score 0):

Bind the navigation li with on mouseenter and on mouseleave (that is what the hover() is doing behind the scenes anyway):

```
$("ul.dropdown li").on('mouseenter', function() {
    $(this).addClass("hover");
    $('ul:first',this).css('visibility', 'visible');
}).on('mouseleave', function() {
    $(this).removeClass("hover");
    $('ul:first',this).css('visibility', 'hidden');
});
```

Then you will have to connect the two somehow (ie. the img and the navigation li), let's say you have an `id` attribute on both, the `li` for instance having `id="news-info"` and the corresponding picture (the `img` tag) having `id="img-news-info`. Then you can bind the click of the picture with:

```
$("#banner img").on('click', function() {
    var navId = $(this).attr('id').substring(4);
    $("#"+navId+"").mouseenter();
});
```

Comment: I don't think you even need to do the first part (splitting the hover function) for the mouseenter trigger to work, but it helps with readability in my opinion.

Comment: Not a problem. webdeveloper's implementation is pretty nifty, though, binding with the indexes, meaning no html modification neccessary.